# Show the list of edited posts

Tags: support, edits

How can I see the list of posts that I have edited **before**?

I want to know how many posts that I have edited (not when I explore my reputation).

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2337837/ziprox09?tab=activity&sort=revisions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two locations in your profile where you can find the information. In general all edits you make result in revisions. Within the activity tab of your profile, you can find all such events by filtering on "revisions".

> [image]

If you are a <2k rep user however, your edits are still suggestions that need a review. If these suggestions are accepted, they will show up under your revisions. However, should you be interested in finding all edits, including those that might have been rejected, then filter by "suggestions".

> [image]

Those two options should give you access to all the edits you've ever made or suggested.